# Problem Installing ROS2

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have just tried to install ROS2 but I have this error when I compile the ros2 bridge:

ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (PyInit__roslz4)

I am using the script:

src/ament/ament_tools/scripts/ament.py

Thank you.

Enrico

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217008/problem-installing-ros2/) by [Enrico](https://answers.ros.org/users/2027/enrico/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2015-09-03

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-09-03**:
Seeing as this is really all experimental stuff, I think it would be better to report this at the main [ros2](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/issues) issue tracker.

**Comment by [Enrico](https://answers.ros.org/users/2027/enrico/) on 2015-09-03**:
Sorry, you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The discussion for this question has moved to github: https://github.com/ros2/ros2/issues/113

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-09-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1